# have an error on gui but windowsForm is find using c++ and opencv

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, image-processing, c++-cli

i have a problem about event of click, move and drag mouse for draw rectangle on Gui. But code about click, move and drag mouse for draw rectangle i will test on visual studio is working fine.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

vector<Rect> rects;
bool bDraw;
Rect r;
Point base;

Mat img;
Mat layer;
Mat working;


void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
    if ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
    {
        cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;    

        // Init your rect
        base.x = x;
        base.y = y;
        r.x = x;
        r.y = y;
        r.width = 0;
        r.height = 0;
        bDraw = true;
    }        
    else if ( event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE )
   {
        cout << "Mouse move over the window - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;

        // If drawing, update rect width and height
        if(!bDraw) return;

        int dx = abs(r.x - x);
        int dy = abs(r.y - y);

        if(x < base.x) {
        r.x = x;
        r.width = abs(x - base.x);
        } else {
            r.width = dx;
        }

        if(y < base.y) {
            r.y = y;
            r.height = abs(y - base.y);
        } else {
            r.height = dy;
    }

    // Refresh
    working = layer.clone();
    rectangle(working, r, Scalar(0,0,0),1);
    imshow("My Window", working);
    waitKey();
}
else if ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
{
    cout << "Left button released" << endl;

    // Save rect, draw it on layer
    rects.push_back(r);
    rectangle(layer, r, Scalar(0,0,255),1);
    //imshow("Layer",layer);
    r = Rect(); 
    bDraw = false;

    // Refresh
    working = layer.clone();

    imshow("My Window", working);
    waitKey();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
bool bDraw = false;

// Read image from file 
img = imread("input/colored_balls.jpg");

// initialize your temp images
layer = img.clone();
working = img.clone();

//if fail to read the image
if( img.empty() ) 
{ 
    cout << "Error loading the image" << endl;
    return -1; 
}

//Create a window
namedWindow("My Window", 1);

//set the callback function for any mouse event
setMouseCallback("My Window", CallBackFunc, NULL);

//show the image
imshow("My Window", working);

// Wait until user press some key
waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

When I copy your same code but basic and paste on my form working with gui. this code will active when push button3. it show picture and get event of mouse but have an error about function to get and event of mouse.

```
void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
    {
        if( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
        {
            cout << "Left button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
        }
        else if( event == EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN )
        {
            cout << "Right button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
        }
        else if( event == EVENT_MBUTTONDOWN )
        {
            cout << "Middle button of the mouse is clicked - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
        }
        else if ( event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE )
        {
            cout << "Mouse move over the window - position (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
        }
    }

    private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

        string a = "";
        MarshalString(textBox1->Text, a);
        Mat img = imread(a);
        if( img.empty() ) 
        { 
            cout << "Error loading the image" << endl;
        }
        namedWindow("Crop picture", 1);
        setMouseCallback("Crop picture", CallBackFunc, NULL);
        imshow("Crop picture",img);

    }
```

error is

> error C3867: 'ProjectFinal::MyForm::CallBackFunc': function call missing argument list; use '&ProjectFinal::MyForm::CallBackFunc' to create a pointer to member   c:\users\nungningz\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\projectfinal\projectfinal\MyForm.h 692 1   ProjectFinal
>
> error C3867: 'ProjectFinal::MyForm::CallBackFunc': function call missing argument list; use '&ProjectFinal::MyForm::CallBackFunc' to create a pointer to member   c:\users\nungningz\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\projectfinal\projectfinal\MyForm.h 692 1   ProjectFinal
>
> IntelliSense: a pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class    c:\Users\NungNingZ\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProjectFinal\ProjectFinal\MyForm.h 692 37  ProjectFinal

if I comment on this error line. it working fine and have and action of push.

Comment: Have you tried writing `setMouseCallback("Crop picture", &ProjectFinal::MyForm::CallBackFunc, NULL);` ?

Comment: I tried to do as you are told. it not working and have error

> error C3374: can't take address of 'ProjectFinal::MyForm::CallBackFunc' unless creating delegate instance c:\users\nungningz\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\projectfinal\projectfinal\MyForm.h 693 1 ProjectFinal

> error C3374: can't take address of 'ProjectFinal::MyForm::CallBackFunc' unless creating delegate instance c:\users\nungningz\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\projectfinal\projectfinal\MyForm.h 693 1 ProjectFinal

Comment: > IntelliSense: a pointer-to-member is not valid for a managed class c:\Users\NungNingZ\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProjectFinal\ProjectFinal\MyForm.h 693 37 ProjectFinal

Comment: well, your form should have some builtin functionality to grab mouse events. Use that. I never used forms, so I can't help you. Sorry about that.